# jQuery fade paragraph when hovering over an internal link

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i have this code:

```
<p>
   Non in porttitor porta. Amet ridiculus? Adipiscing cum scelerisque aliquam, tortor ac mauris platea? Vel in amet non nec facilisis, phasellus.<br /> 
   Sagittis diam auctor ultricies in habitasse integer vel duis sociis rhoncus
   <a href="something.html">porttitor</a>?
</p>
```

i want to fade out all other text in the paragraph except the text in the anchor tag when hovered on the link to a certain opacity and then make it normal again when unhovered. i want to do this in jquery. i am doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p a').hover(function() {
        $(this).parent('p').not('a').animate({
             opacity: "0.5"
        }, 3000);
        },
        function() {
        $(this).parent('p').not('a').animate({
             opacity: "1"
        }, 3000);
     });
 });
```

but it isnt working!! please help guys....
i know this technique is totally wrong... but if you can make it

Comment: The problem here is, that if the `p` is faded out, all its content is faded, also the `a`.

Comment: yes @dave i assumed that. can you just then tell a totally new technique if possible. thnx in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opacity affects all children of the affected element.

You would need to animate the opacity of the `color` property (*the alpha channel*).

To do that though you need an **rgba** capable browser (*not IE*) and a plugin to do it.

[jQuery UI extends the `animate` method<sup>docs</sup>](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) to allow for animation to `color` and `background-color` but not for the **rgba** version yet.

So, instead, you can use the plugin at http://pioupioum.fr/sandbox/jquery-color/ and do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p a').hover(function() {
        $(this).parent('p').animate({
             color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
        }, 500);
        },
        function() {
        $(this).parent('p').animate({
             color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
        }, 500);
     });
 });
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/hfc83/

Comment: thnx a ton...!! thnq thnq and thnq... u just made my day!! :) but can you just tell me in which web browsers it really works?? plz...

Comment: @Devashish, all (*FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera*) but IE (*up to IE8*). I do not have IE9 installed so can't tell. (*according to [Internet Explorer 9 Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705#_CSS3_Colors) it should support it*)

Answer (score 0):

This should be cross browser, just wraps all the text in the paragraph with a span except for the a element inside of the paragraph and then fades out the span elements.

I use the visibility to keep the link in place of the paragraph otherwise it jumps to the beginning of the paragraph because the spans are hidden with display:none.

You can check it out on http://jsfiddle.net/FQfmJ/13/

```
$("p a").hover(function(){
       var p =  $(this).parent();
       p.contents(":not(a)").wrap("<span />");

       p.find("span").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).removeAttr("style").css("visibility","hidden");
       });
   },function(){   
       $(this).parent().find("span").removeAttr("style").hide().fadeIn();
   }
);
```